# The appropriate confidence interval for an odds ratio

Tags: confidence-interval, odds-ratio

I conducted an odds ratio test with a certain software, and I'm not sure about the right confidence interval (CI) to use.
The 2x2 table consists the distribution of counts as follows, by each cell: a=26, b=21, c=12, d=2. The output of the results included the calculated OR, with the following four types of CIs: Mid-p exact, Fisher's exact, Cornfield, Wald. The question is: based on the distribution of the observations, particularly considering that cell d includes 2 observations (<5), which of the four abovementioned CIs is the most appropriate to use?

Answer (score 1):

I'd be reading published evaluations of methods for computing odds ratio intervals. [Ruxton and Neuhauser 2013 (Methods Ecol Evol 4)](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00250.x) recommended the unconditional score interval method from [Agresti and Min 2002 (Biostatistics 3)](https://academic.oup.com/biostatistics/article/3/3/379/306622?login=true). The score interval can be computed using the *orscoreci* function in the [PropCIs R package](https://cran.microsoft.com/web/packages/PropCIs/index.html).

The mid-p could be the best of the four estimates you have.

Thanks for raising this question because it prompted me to find a solution for computing risk ratios for 2 x 2 contingency tables.